# With Firefox/Firebug, Why do You Only Get Stacktraces With Some Errors

Tags: firebug, stack-trace

I've noticed that with Firefox/Firebug (my main development environment), *some* errors produce stack traces, while others don't.  At first I thought this had something to do with whether I generated the error (eg. new Error("foo")) or whether Javascript generated it (eg. undefinedFoo += 1), but I've noticed it happening with both types of errors.

So, my question is, does anyone know what causes this?  Is it random or is there some pattern/logic to it?  Is it just Firefox and/or Firebug being lame or do other browsers do this too?  And most importantly, is there anything I can do to control it (specifically to make it always give me stack traces)?

This isn't a crucial question (as I can always throw a "console.trace()" just before whatever line the error occurs on), but I'm curious if anyone knows the answer.

**********EDIT**********

I found this thread:
http://groups.google.com/group/firebug/browse_thread/thread/1f32df8b96ec1d30/64b9074cb99056c2?pli=1
which mentions that Firefox doesn't provide Firebug with stacktraces if the error isn't an instance of Error.  In other words, if you throw something that isn't new Error("foo"), you won't get a stacktrace.

However, this doesn't help me, as I'm not seeing stacktraces even when I throw new Error().

Comment: Although I doubt it matters, I should probably mention that I'm on Linux (on the off chance that Firefox has a Linux-specific bug with losing the stacktrace).

Comment: Am I the only one who sees stack-trace-less errors in Firefox?  Or do others see them, and just no one knows why Firefox does that?

Comment: I found a partial answer.  It turns out that Firebug has a "secret" (ie. about:config) preference that makes it not show stacktraces: extensions.firebug.showStackTrace.  When I checked my about:config, I found that this preference was set to false (which is odd, as I don't remember ever doing that ...).  However, even with it set to true (and even after I restarted Firefox) I still don't see stack traces on some errors :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it!  It turns out the module pattern is the problem.  Here's a simple example:

```
var OuterModule = (function(module){
    module.throwError = function() {
        throw new Error("This has no stack trace!");
    };
    return module;
})({});
OuterModule.throwError();
```

For some reason, because the module pattern hides throwError function inside the module's scope, Firebug/Firefox is unable to trace it properly.

Man that took forever too figure out; hopefully someone else will benefit from my suffering :-)

Comment: As a side note, this is clearly not an inherent limitation of Firebug/Firefox, because if you add a "console.trace()" right before you throw the new Error, you'll get a perfectly usable stack trace.  So the issue isn't that Firefox can't handle stack traces that originate from inside "modules"; the problem is that Firefox seems to have difficulty connecting those stack traces to errors that happen inside "modules".

Comment: I noticed similar behavior and also had a feeling it was related to application's errors thrown with **new Error** as opposed to error thrown by the system - Thanks for this post!